# Access Windows namespace from F# Library

Tags: f#, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I am trying to create a F# Library to use with Windows Store apps. I need access to the Windows namespace (especially `Windows.Storage`). What type of project should I choose for the library?

When I select F# Portable Library, there is no way to add reference to Windows.Storage, neither when I create a project of type F# Library. I am looking for something like Class Library (Windows Store Apps)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found `Windows.Storage` in here: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\References\CommonConfiguration\Neutral\Windows.winmd`. This means that F# cannot directly reference it.

I suggest that you model your back-end around it (you do have to combine C# with your F# code, because F# doesn't work on its own with Windows 8).